# Java Print Products in Basket

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist

Trying to wrap my head around something I've been trying to do with little to no success today I figured I'd go ask the smart guys at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

What I am trying to do is create two classes: Basket and Product. The Product class looks like this:

```
public class Product
    {
    private final String identifier;
    private final float price;
    public Product(final String productIdentifier, float productPrice) {
        identifier = productIdentifier;
        price = productPrice;
    }
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }
    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(identifier + "   " + price + " EUR");
    }
}
```

The Basket class I am now trying to do is supposed to be able to do a few things. First and most importantly it is supposed to add products to the basket and print them out on the console. The latter is what I am having huge difficulties with.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Basket
{
    private ArrayList<Product> products;

    public Basket()
    {
        produkte = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }
    public void addProduct(final String productIdentifier, final float productPrice)
    {
        produkte.add( new Product (productIdentifier, productPrice));
    }
    public void printBasket() 
    {
        //Print products in basket using the print() function of the Product class.
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of things to get it to print out the products I added. However they were so fruitless that I find myself here asking for help now.

What I have tried so far looked something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) 
{
    Product.print();
}
```

What this throws back at me is that I cant use print() in a static context. So I have tried making print() a static function, that won't work though, because I am using the non-static variables identifier and price in it.

I feel like what I am missing is just a little thing, however being new to Java I am probably just missing it big time. What I hope for is a nudge into the right direction and to be pointed out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it's an easy mistake to make. The key thing to remember here is that you have to access the specific object reference rather than a class name. `Product.print()` means you are doing some static method that doesn't relate to a specific `Product` object. The method would have to be declared as a `static` method for this to work. For an example of where this is used, look at the `Math` object in the java api. ControlAltDel's answer will steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have `Product.print();`

try `products.get(i).print();`

should fix it

Comment: It did fix it. -facepalm- I knew it was something simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Call the Product's print method from an instantiated Product object and you're ready to go. You have to specify which Product object is printing, otherwise you won't know which variables to use (that's why static won't work).

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that you need a loop, but this isn't right:

```
for(int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) 
{
    Product.print();
}
```

`Product` is a class, so you can't call non-static methods on it. You want to be calling `print` on the objects in your list, not on the whole class. To do this, we have to "loop through" the list to access each object in it in turn:

```
for(int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) 
{
    products.get(i).print();
}
```

You could also use a for-each loop, which makes it very clear that you re processing every element in the list (because this what these loops are used for):

```
for(Product p : products) 
{
    p.print();
}
```